# Object.entries that keeps "keyof T" information?

Tags: typescript

Given this example, how can I make `e` have the type `Partial<Person>`?

```js
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const p1: Person = { age: 1, name: 'a' };

const p2: Partial<Person> = { age: 1 };

const e = Object.entries(p2).filter(([k, v]) => (
  p1[k] !== v
));
```

By setting `e` to `Partial<Person>` it says:

```
Type '[string, string | number][]' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Person>'.ts(2559)
```

Comment: What do you mean with *reconstruct*?

Comment: I mean retain type information that in reality it's a Partial<Person>.

Comment: But `e` does *not* have that type; it is an array of tuples. The error message is accurate.